# Go (lang) can not find module

Tags: go

I did `go get github.com/nanobox-io/golang-scribble`, but when i try to run the main.go i get the error

```
[jerome@thearch beer-server]$ go run main.go
../../pkg/storage/json/repository.go:14:2: cannot find package "github.com/nanobox.io/golang-scribble" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go/src/github.com/nanobox.io/golang-scribble (from $GOROOT)
    /home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex/src/github.com/nanobox.io/golang-scribble (from $GOPATH)
```

so i searched it:

```
[jerome@thearch nanobox-io]$ find /home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex/src/github.com/nanobox.io -name golang-scribble
find: ‘/home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex/src/github.com/nanobox.io’: No such file or directory
```

There is the thing completly weird, i cd follow the link and the package golang-scribble is present at the right place. So i pwd to get the path and use it to run the same cmd as previously

```
[jerome@thearch nanobox-io]$ pwd
    /home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex/src/github.com/nanobox-io
    
[jerome@thearch nanobox-io]$ ls
    golang-scribble
    
[jerome@thearch nanobox-io]$ find /home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex/src/github.com/nanobox-io  -name golang-scribble
        /home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex/src/github.com/nanobox-io/golang-scribble
```

I don t know what's wrong ?
If i add some other package like github.com/google/uuid or julienschmidt/httprouter, it works perfectly.

extra-info

```
go version go1.16.2 linux/amd64
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOPATH="/home/jerome/Documents/code/go/domainhex"

Operating System: Arch Linux
Kernel: Linux 5.11.6-arch1-1
Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: Can you spot the difference between `nanobox.io` and `nanobox-io`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `go get` on `github.com/nanobox-io/golang-scribble` but you're importing `github.com/nanobox.io/golang-scribble`, the difference being `nanobox-io` vs `nanobox.io`. Try changing your import statement to `github.com/nanobox-io/golang-scribble`.